# Python Pandas getting hierarchy path till top management

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below pandas DF

[image]

steps to create the DF

```
data=[['1','0','0','0','0'],['2','1','1','0','0|0'],['3','1','1','1','0|1'],['4','2','2','0','0|0|0'],['5','2','2','1','0|0|1'],['6','2','2','2','0|0|2'],['7','3','2','0','0|1|0'],['8','3','2','1','0|1|1'],['9','3','2','2','0|1|2'],['10','3','2','3','0|1|3'],['11','4','3','0','0|0|0|0'],['12','4','3','1','0|0|0|1'],['13','10','3','0','0|1|3|0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['eid','m_eid','level','path_variable','complete_path'])
df=df.drop('complete_path',axis=1)
```

Here:

**eid** = employee id

**m_eid** = manager id

**level** = level in org(0 being top boss)

**path_variable** = incremental number assigned to an employee based on there level this number resets for each manager(for example: eid[4,5,6,7,8,9,10] belong to same level 2 but eid[4,5,6] has same manager(m_eid=2) so there path_variable is 0,1,2 whereas eid[7,8,9,10] has a different manager(m_eid=3) so the path_variable restarts from 0)

i want to create a new column which shows the complete path till level 0 for each eid. Like shown below:

[image: output]

Complete path is concatenations of path_variable till level 0(top boss).

Its like path from root node to the edge node. For ex. lets take eid 10

[image]

there can be level skips between immediate managers. I m trying to avoid iterrows() due to performance constraints.

Comment: You need top explain the logic for creating your desired output.  For example, how do you derive the result for eid = 3 in you desired output. o not provide this explanation as a comment, but edit your question to Include this explanation.

Comment: @itprorh66 added more explanation in the question, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can build a directed graph with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), then find the [`shortest_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path) between each node and `'0'`, then use that to map the `path_variable`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='m_eid', target='eid',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

s = df.set_index('eid')['path_variable']

mapper = {n: '|'.join(s.get(x, '') for x in 
                      nx.shortest_path(G, source='0',
                                       target=n)[1:])
          for n in df['eid'].unique()
         }
df['complete_path'] = df['eid'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   eid m_eid level path_variable complete_path
0    1     0     0             0             0
1    2     1     1             0           0|0
2    3     1     1             1           0|1
3    4     2     2             0         0|0|0
4    5     2     2             1         0|0|1
5    6     2     2             2         0|0|2
6    7     3     2             0         0|1|0
7    8     3     2             1         0|1|1
8    9     3     2             2         0|1|2
9   10     3     2             3         0|1|3
10  11     4     3             0       0|0|0|0
11  12     4     3             1       0|0|0|1
12  13    10     3             0       0|1|3|0
```

Graph:

[image: organization graph, networkx graphviz]

If you already have unique values in `eid` you could avoid the mapper and use:

```
df['complete_path'] = ['|'.join(s.get(x, '') for x in 
                       nx.shortest_path(G, source=n,
                                        target='0')[-2::-1])
                       for n in df['eid']]
```

---

To make it easier to understand, here is a more classical path with the nodes ids (not the path_variables):

```
mapper = {n: '|'.join(nx.shortest_path(G, source='0',
                                       target=n)[1:])
          for n in df['eid'].unique()
         }
df['complete_path'] = df['eid'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   eid m_eid level path_variable complete_path
0    1     0     0             0             1
1    2     1     1             0           1|2
2    3     1     1             1           1|3
3    4     2     2             0         1|2|4
4    5     2     2             1         1|2|5
5    6     2     2             2         1|2|6
6    7     3     2             0         1|3|7
7    8     3     2             1         1|3|8
8    9     3     2             2         1|3|9
9   10     3     2             3        1|3|10
10  11     4     3             0      1|2|4|11
11  12     4     3             1      1|2|4|12
12  13    10     3             0     1|3|10|13
```

Comment: I just inverted the logic to have the "top boss" as root

Comment: I was about to post [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/jUcKF2WQ) one but you were smarter/faster. My answer wouldn't have been as complete and impressive as yours, anyways ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks for the quick answer, although i have more complex data (e_id) are alphanumeric and there are more than 1 "top boss" so its not able to find shortest path.

Comment: @AkshitChauhan you can post a follow-up question if you like. Depending on whether or not the different top bosses are head of isolated branches, there could be workarounds to that. If you post another question, please give a minimal example that reflects those constraints. The alphanumeric ids shouldn't make a difference (networkx can use any hashable object as node)